# implicit conversion (varchar to varbinary) not allowed, use the CONVERT

Tags: c#, sql

Estou tentando fazer um sistema que obtem imagens e as salvas em um banco de dados especifico, porem não consigo resolver esse erro (ja apliquei o CONVERT no SQL mas não resolveu).
(Area do erro)

```
//Aqui vai entrar a gravação do db
SqlConnection conect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand comm = null;
    string strSQL;
    string baseimage;
    conect.Open();
    method = converter(imagensPictureBox.Image);
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.[Dados principais](Denuncias, [Denuncia ID], Empresa, Data, Denunciado,Imagens)VALUES('" + denunciasTextBox.Text + "', '" + denuncia_IDTextBox.Text + "', '" + empresaComboBox.Text + "', '" + dataDateTimePicker.Value.ToString() + "', '" + denunciadoTextBox.Text + "','" + methodToaBase64String + "')";
    comm = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conect);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conect.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Denúncia arquivada");
}
catch (Exception xx)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erro detectado" + xx.Message);
}       
// Aqui fecha a db.
```

Converter é uma função que passa a imagem para Byte[].
            Estou alocando o dado em uma coluna varbinary.

Comment: Obs.: "Base64" é uma string não um array de bytes

Comment: sim, eu converti e esqueci de avisar no topico

Comment: Nunca, jamais, em hipótese alguma nesse mundo faça concatenação de string ao montar comandos em SQL. Se eu injetar um código por mais simples que seja nesses componentes de texto seu, eu posso apagar seu banco inteiro ou criar uma função que a cada inserção de registro posso mandar para um host externo. Além disso, como é sql server, armazena a imagem em um blob no banco de dados, pegando os bytes da imagem. E novamente, usa parametros no insert, eles já tratam os tipos do sql sem ter que fazer conversão.

Comment: então eu salvo em blob não em varbinary?

Comment: Pode ser em varbinary, mas como o colega falou, use parêmetros tipados

Comment: Poderiam me explicar o que seriam esses parametros tipados ? Procurei na internet e não achei nada muito conclusivo.